# Why don't I have SubmitChanges?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is this something that's been changed in MVC 3? There is no `SubmitChanges()` method anywhere and I can't figure out, I seem to have the proper namespace too (`System.Data.Linq`).

The only thing I find is `SaveChanges()` instead. Are they the same? Or have I run into something strange here?

Answer (score 1):

They are conceptually the same, although their implementations are different.

- [SaveChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792.aspx) is part of ObjectContext in Entity Framework.
- [SubmitChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges.aspx) is part of DataContext in Linq to SQL.